# I have an SMD switch how can I find the part number?

Tags: switches, identification, surface-mount

[image]I have an SMD switch but I don't know its part number. I searched suppliers sites like Digikey and ... but I couldn't find it. Is there any other way to find the part Number? The size is 6*6*5(length*width*height).It is momentary and normally open.This code is on it : 80410A

[![SMD switch][2]][2]

Comment: You should post the dimensions, and the distance between the solder pads

Comment: You really need to post clear well focused pictures of the switch including any markings.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find the part number of some switch that you have, when that device has no markings, is to search and search. Before you begin your search it is necessary to have on hand data such as:

1. Switching Function (SPST, DPDT etc)
2. Body Size (mm or other units)
3. Lead Configuration and Spacing

Then you check online catalogues from multiple sources such as Digikey, Mouser, RS Components etc. Also check online manufacturer web sites from common switch sources.

As a last resort sometimes it can be productive to post a picture here with your question. Sometimes you may get lucky if a reader here recognizes the type of switch. Obviously clear well focused pictures are much more useful in this regard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Size is 6*6*5 mm. There is a code on it. can it be useful?

Comment: @sami Gah. Of course the code can be useful. You need to post it in the question.

Comment: @sami - You have a lot to learn here. You need to post all the information you have into your question. Even your size data is incomplete because only you know which number is the height, length or width. Still missing are important details like switching function, momentary/alternate, normally open or normally closed. Even you would have trouble matching possible substitute switches in your searching and searching without this information.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will add this data to the question.